# using your own ftp server to receive uploaded files on my website

Tags: ftp

Im looking for an out of the box solution to be able to add an upload form so that my users can upload large files from my website onto my own FTP server.

Has anyone found a good service to accomplish this?  Again I want to be able to use my own server in my office and i also need a form attached to the uploaded file.

I run a graphics printing company and need to be able to receive large files that my designers send to me.

I want my user experience to be painless and not complicated as possible so i would prefer if they did not have to download any FTP clients like filezilla or transmit.

I just want them to fill out the form 
upload their files 
click send

then i receive it on my server

If there is any off the shelves solution for this that would be amazing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is an "out of the box" web app.  It allows you to brand the app to look like your own web site by modifying a couple of files.  All the functionality is built in.  It is called Simple2FTP and can be found at www.Simple2ftp.com

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining a ftp server is not trivial.  There are various dropbox-type services on the
web that are very easy to use.

Comment: i've looked into most of them and contacted their customer support but they said it was not possible to use your own ftp server.  You would have to use theirs.